# The 'Run Command' dialog has corrupted graphics. Any ideas on fixing this?

Tags: graphics, kde, visual-artifacts, krunner

I'm using KDE, and whenever I open the 'Run Command' dialog (e.g. with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>), the dialog is filled with corrupted graphics. Sometimes it's possible to see enough of the dialog to use it, but usually it's too messed up to use. Closing it and re-opening it changes its appearance: the graphics glitches are apparently random. There are no other graphics related issues with the user interface besides this one.